# Get minimum value from list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a class ABC like this

```
public class ABC{
public int Id {get;set;}
public int UserCount {get;set;}
}
```

Now I add following records to a list of type ABC

```
List<ABC> lstABC = new List<ABC>();
lstABC.Add(new ABC(){Id=1,UserCount=5});
lstABC.Add(new ABC(){Id=2,UserCount=15});
lstABC.Add(new ABC(){Id=3,UserCount=3});
lstABC.Add(new ABC(){Id=4,UserCount=20});
```

I've another list of type int

```
List<int> lstIds = new List<int>();
lstIds.Add(1);
lstIds.Add(3);
lstIds.Add(4);
```

Now i want to find out the minimum value of `UserCount` by comparing both the list where `Id` in `lstABC` should match the items presesnt in `lstIds`. I can get the minimum value of `UserCount` by using loops but is there any another way to get the value in an optimized way by avoiding loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Join` to link both lists:

```
var joined = from id in lstIds
             join x in lstABC 
             on id equals x.Id 
             select x;
int minValue = joined.Min(x => x.UserCount);
```

This is more efficient than loops since `Join` uses a set to find matching items.

There's more than one way to skin a cat, this is a little bit less efficient:

```
int minValue = lstABC.Where(x => lstIds.Contains(x.ID)).Min(x => x.UserCount);
```

Comment: I'll go with first approach.. second approach will create problem for ids `1` and `11`.Thanks :)

Comment: @SidM: the `Contains` is not a sub-string  approach. `lstIds` is a `List<int>` and `List.Contains` looks if there is at least one with the exact same ID in the list and `1 != 11`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
        int min = lstABC.Min(entry => entry.UserCount);
        var a = lstABC.Where(e => e.UserCount == min).FirstOrDefault();
        var resul = lstIds.Where(e => e.Equals(a.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
        var result = lstABC.Where(n =>n.Id == resul).FirstOrDefault();
```